# Airflow install problem SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, airflow

Im trying to install airflow on Ubuntu.

I set up a virtualenv with python 3.5.3 and tried to install airflow this way :

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel \
    && pip install Cython \
    && pip install pytz \
    && pip install pyOpenSSL \
    && pip install ndg-httpsclient \
    && pip install pyasn1 \
    && pip install python-crontab \
    && pip install crontabs \
    && pip install py4j==0.10.7\
    && pip install thrift-sasl==0.2.1\
    && pip install git+https://github.com/tobes/snakebite.git@python-3-long \
    && pip install apache-airflow[crypto,devel_hadoop,mysql]==1.10.9 \
    && pip install werkzeug==0.16.1
```

But im having this error

```
Using cached protobuf-2.5.0.tar.gz (68 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/arslane/airflow/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cnsf0k86/protobuf_49e7336cd75a470cbb1c2c76bfa70896/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cnsf0k86/protobuf_49e7336cd75a470cbb1c2c76bfa70896/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-jd672mun
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-cnsf0k86/protobuf_49e7336cd75a470cbb1c2c76bfa70896/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-cnsf0k86/protobuf_49e7336cd75a470cbb1c2c76bfa70896/setup.py", line 52
        print "Generating %s..." % output
                               ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anyone help me up with that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following i.e. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/constraints-1.10.9/constraints-3.5.txt (Constraints file for Airflow 1.10.9 and Python 3.5):

```
pip install -U 'pip<20.3' setuptools wheel \
    && pip install Cython \
    && pip install pytz \
    && pip install pyOpenSSL \
    && pip install ndg-httpsclient \
    && pip install pyasn1 \
    && pip install python-crontab \
    && pip install crontabs \
    && pip install py4j==0.10.7\
    && pip install thrift-sasl==0.2.1\
    && pip install git+https://github.com/tobes/snakebite.git@python-3-long \
    && pip install protobuf==3.11.3
    && pip install apache-airflow[crypto,devel_hadoop,mysql]==1.10.9 -c https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/constraints-1.10.9/constraints-3.5.txt \
    && pip install werkzeug==0.16.1
```

I think the error you see is because of the old version of Protobuf

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Now i have this error : `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement future<0.17,>=0.16.0 (from apache-airflow[crypto,devel-hadoop,mysql])
ERROR: No matching distribution found for future<0.17,>=0.16.0`

Comment: Updated the answer, try that

Comment: Now i have the previous error lmao `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`

Comment: I have updated the answer to use `pip<20.3` . PIP released 20.3 that contains new resolver

Comment: Idk why he processes the `<20.3` as a redirection. I have this error now : `-bash: 20.3: No such file or directory`

Comment: Use `pip install -U 'pip<20.3'` -- I have updated the answer too. Some terminals don't like it without single / dobuel quotes